# sql server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to write trigger that after inserting record to table Person I would like to create new record in table Car with PersonID = newly inserter ID from table Person:

Person:
ID
Name

Car:
ID
PersonID //FK to Person
Name

thanks for any hint, bye

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to create code that is so unmaintainable that your customer/employer can never be without you. Clever move!

Comment: I just wanted to know the mechanism of creating trigger like that. It isnt real world example :P

Comment: Where can Ypu see my axcept rate ?

Comment: @PtotatoMan: right here: http://i56.tinypic.com/119cfg6.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you would have something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterPersonInsert
ON dbo.Person AFTER INSERT 
AS BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.Car(PersonID)
      SELECT i.PersonID 
      FROM INSERTED i
END
```

The important point to remember is: if you insert 10 people into your table in a single statement, your trigger will be called **once** with a "pseudo-table" `INSERTED` containing those ten people.

So your trigger code needs to be set-aware - do **not** assume the trigger gets called once for each row - that is not the case.

See the [MSDN docs for CREATE TRIGGER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms189799.aspx) for more details, and check out the [An Introduction To Triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i) tutorial on SQL Team.